# Can I build container on Win10 and next run it on Windows Server 2019 or 2022?

Tags: windows, docker

Can I build container on Win10 and next run it on Windows Server 2019 or 2022?
Is it supported?
I cannot find any official documentation about this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Docker containers are designed to run on any platform, as long as the host can run docker (which Windows Home/Pro/Server) all can, then it should be able to run any docker container.

You can save and export a container you've made using the `commit` and `save` commands in docker.

e.g:

```
docker commit <container> <repository_name>:<tag (optional)>

# This will create a new image with the repository name and tag

docker save <image_name> -o <filename>.tar

# This will output that image to a .tar file

docker load -i <filename.tar>

# This will import the saved .tar as a new image.
```